# Eigenvalues FEAST method - performance is very variable

Tags: performance-tuning, linear-algebra

I am running the `FEAST` method option for `Eigenvalues` on sparse matrices of dimension around 500,000.  I look for about 50 eigenvalues.  I have noticed a massive sensitivity of performance on what the entries are.

For example, I can have two sparse matrices with exactly the same entries non-zero.  I simply modify the complex phase of some entries.  This can result in runtimes of 5x longer or more.

Has anyone encountered this problem or any possible solutions?

Comment: Hello, this sounds like an interesting question. Obviously you can't post your actual data if it's that large, but have you managed to isolate the issue to a small matrix that has the same sensitivity of performance to small changes?

Comment: I will be on the lookout for that, but I only really noticed for dimension greater than 10^5.